# Rules for merging map markers at scale in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a map of Australia, plotting cafes.  As I change the scale, these markers cluster too tightly to be useful.  Point displacement is also not useful, and a heat map is too indistinct.  What I'd like to do have those markers collapse into one marker, which displays a count of nearby markers.  For example, I'd like, when the zoom reaches 5000:1, for a single map marker to display "78" - the number of individual markers that are close to each other at that scale at Sydney's CBD.

I expect this is going to involve a complex render rule.  Is this the best way to do this?  If so can you give me a pointer as to how to call the scale factor in the rule, and how to set the point to which the markers collapse?

Answer (score 4):

With QGIS 3.2, you can use the symbology "Point cluster" (layer properties-symbology)

An example:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]